# Visual Studio Team Services how to publish code documentation

Tags: visual-studio, build, azure-devops, code-documentation

My intention is to improve the code documentation of our Visual Studio C# solutions. Therefore I want to upload the xml-based C# documentation to Visual Studio Team Services.

**Option 1:** Doxygen

- there is a package for doxygen, which can be added to the build definition
- then the documentation is included at the menu of the vsts as pdf-file.

But i'm looking more for a solution to build the code docu as a html-file and publish it e.g in the project wiki at VSTS.

**Option 2:** Preferred but not found

- create the documentation as a html file
- add it to the VSTS project wiki or dashboard

Is there a package for VSTS to implement option 2? Can someone describe the way, how to implement option 2?

Comment: You can upvote for the feature here - https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20013283-allow-for-html-files-to-be-uploaded-to-vsts-wiki.

Answer (score 0):

The html file is not supported for VSTS project wiki, but it supports some HTML tags, so you can create a wiki page with HTML tags.

For example:

```
<p>This text needs to <del>strikethrough</del> <ins>since it is redundant</ins>!</p>
<p><tt>This text is teletype text.</tt></p>
<font color="blue">Colored text</font>
<center>This text will be center-aligned.</center>
<p>This text contains <sup>superscript</sup> text.</p> 
<p>This text contains <sub>subscript</sub> text.</p>
<p>The project status is <span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">GREEN</span> even though the bug count / developer may be in <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">red.</span> - Capability of span
<p><small>Disclaimer: Wiki also supports showing small text</small></p>
<p><big>Bigger text</big></p>
```

[Syntax guidance for Markdown files, widgets, wikis, and pull request comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/markdown-guidance)

Since each team project wiki employs a git repository backend, you can update it offline (Clone > modify/create files > Commit > Push).

[Clone and update wiki pages offline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/wiki-update-offline)

Comment: Thanks, so maybe the easiest way is to produce a html and add it to the wiki ressources, then link in the wiki to this html, or i reate directly markdown files from the xml doc, e.g with https://gist.github.com/lontivero/593fc51f1208555112e0.

Comment: Generate the markdown files per to xml/html doc automatically is the better way.